# How to get the content of this html code in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to get the value "https://connect.facebook.net..." which is present in the li tag. I tried with the below options but it is returning as NULL string in Selenium.

HTML code as below:

```
 <ul>
   <li>Script</li>
   <li>https://connect.facebook.net/?v=2.8.1:0</li>
 </ul>
```

Tried code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*/li[2][contains(@text,'')]")).getText()

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[2]")).getText()

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[2]")).getAttribute("value")
```

All the above is returning value as 0.

Comment: Hello! Could you please put the `html` in the question? Thank you :)

Comment: None of your examples above are valid xpath locators, but I have no idea what it is you're even trying to locate.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the html code in my question.

Comment: paste full HTML

Comment: @BillHileman can you elaborate on why the above is not valid for `By.xpath`? Unless there was an edit, except maybe the first one but I haven't confirmed.

Comment: Too late to edit, what I meant to say was I don't see an issue with the xpath unless there was an edit.

Comment: It's just not a full traditional xpath - the XML code segment was not present when I made my original comment.  Based on the snippet you show, they would be valid xpaths, I believe, but they may not work when applied to the entire HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that using the below code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[2]")).getAttribute("innerText")
```

What are the different values which can be expected or used for .getAttribute Method? It would be of great help if any shares me the details.

Comment: You can get any attribute values for the element itself. For example, with this element: `<div class='some' style='fanciness' value='thing'>`, you can get the values for `class`, `style`, and `value` using `getAttribute`. You can also do things like `innerText` as you've discovered.